# Make a Dockerfile automatically from a Python project

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a python project as below:

```
project
|___build.py
|___scrip1.py
|___script2.py
|___main.py
```

The *main.py* file uses functions and datasets developed in scrip1.py and script2.py. The build.py has all the needed libraries/packages

For now I am making a Dockerfile manually:

```
FROM python
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
RUN pip3 install scipy
ADD script1.py /
ADD script2.py /
ADD main.py /
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

I am installing manually all the libraries needed in the build.py.

How can I automate the creation of a Dockerfile based on a python project? So instead of making the file manually I can run the script to make the Dockerfile.

Comment: You have to create the original docker file by you itself. However the dependencies can be moved to a `requirements.txt` file and installed from there

Comment: usually you'll want a `requirements.txt` that contains all of your needed packages so that you can just `RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Also, your `ADD` instructions can be replaced by a single `COPY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of a package handle using pip, on your directory you can run:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create a requirements.txt containing all packages to run your project.

Now in your Dockerfile

```
FROM python
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD script1.py /
ADD script2.py /
ADD main.py /
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

One small optimization on your Dockerfile is replacing the *ADD* commands to just one *COPY*

```
FROM python
COPY . /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

From [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

Comment: Hey Thanks! But what can I do to add the python scripts in the project automatically ?

Comment: You can put all of your python scripts on the same directory and then COPY the hole directory using _COPY directory /_. Got it?

Comment: Of course, you also need to copy in `requirements.txt` in order for this to work.